# Youtube like view in landscape mode using size classes in Ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, autolayout, landscape-portrait, size-classes

I need to change my existent view in landscape to something similar like Youtube does in landscape .. Currently i'm using size classes and storyboard to achieve it but the problem is my layout should change considerably in landscape compared to the portrait and since the size classes for both ipad portrait and landscape is same ,should i use a separate view controller for the landscape version .. My current portrait view is also slightly complex which has child view controllers embedded in it .. What is the best approach to follow for the seamless transition from ipad portrait to landscape ..Do you think youtube is using different viewcontrollers/xib's to achieve it .. Another problem is this code has been written by some other company and the instructions given to me is to not change the existent code much .. I dont want to fiddle with it much ..

PFA for the images of how the current version looks and how it should look like landscape..
Current version

[image]

Proposed version

[image]

Edit 1: I have already implemented viewWillTransitionToSize in my view controller .. My question is, should i be using two different xib's or can i use a different view controller altogether for landscape version ..What are the pros and cons of it ? As evident from the below pics , i need to do quite a few changes to my landscape version ..

reduce the size of video , hide the segmented control and add two tableviews to the side..

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the [UIContentContainer protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:) method viewWillTransitionToSize and check the width and/or height of size with your view controller's view's frame and act accordingly.

In Swift:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize,
    withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {


        if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .Regular && traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .Regular {

            if size.width > self.view.frame.size.width {

                // Moving to landscape

            } else {
                // Moving to portrait
            }
        }
}
```

> **Discussion**
>
> UIKit calls this method before changing the size of a
>   presented view controller’s view. You can override this method in your
>   own objects and use it to perform additional tasks related to the size
>   change. For example, a container view controller might use this method
>   to override the traits of its embedded child view controllers. Use the
>   provided coordinator object to animate any changes you make.
>
> If you override this method in your custom view controllers, always
>   call super at some point in your implementation so that UIKit can
>   forward the size change message appropriately. View controllers
>   forward the size change message to their views and child view
>   controllers. Presentation controllers forward the size change to their
>   presented view controller.

Comment: It is already in place and tracks the changes of video in full screen and partial screen .. As shown in the images of the question ,since in landscape mode ,i need to do a lot of changes should i be using two different xib's / create a new view controller for landscape version.. As i have said i dont want to fiddle with existing code much..

Comment: I would track the changes you need to make and decide if they are **too** big to handle in the current view controller then use another view controller to represent the landscape orientation, otherwise try to make the changes in the current view controller.